# How to fix setOnClickListener code that causes crash

Tags: android-studio, onclicklistener, android-cardview

I am having difficulty in figuring out what is wrong with my code, My code runs when the onclick listener is not yet implemented but once I implement the onclick listener it crashes.

```
 public class menu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private CardView assess, profile, chatbot, breathing;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        assess = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.assess);
        profile = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        chatbot = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.chatbot);
        breathing = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.breathing);

//        assess.setOnClickListener(this);
//        profile.setOnClickListener(this);
//        chatbot.setOnClickListener(this);
//        breathing.setOnClickListener(this);






        }
        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

//        Intent i;
//
//        switch (v.getId()){
//
//
//            case R.id.assess :
//                i = new Intent(this,depression_assessment.class);
//                startActivity(i);
//                break;






        }


    }
//}
```

When I tried debugging the codes, these lines are the cause of the crash.

```
//        assess.setOnClickListener(this);
//        profile.setOnClickListener(this);
//        chatbot.setOnClickListener(this);
//        breathing.setOnClickListener(this);
```

It is where the problem is starting because the code works even though the onclick is blank. When I checked the logs it shows this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.thesis/com.example.thesis.menu}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code, but this could be due to serveral reasons:

This line of code `breathing = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.breathing);` will look for a view with id `breathing` inside your activity's layout, and according to the error it is null, which means it did not find it within the same activity's layout, so make sure your cardView is in this activity's layout. Another possible reason is that you might have duplicate Ids in your xml files, in this case,find the duplicate and rename the Ids.

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying, it turns out I have 2 menu xml files, one is the normal xml and the other one is the v21. I am using the normal xml file but the layout the code uses is the v21 one. it's all good now.

Comment: Glad to know it's fixed now!